# How to find item by type from a list in scala?

Tags: scala

Say I have defined:

```
sealed trait ValidationResult
object Valid extends ValidationResult
case class Invalid(error:String) extends ValidationResult
```

Then I have a list which contains some validation results:

```
val results = List(Valid, Invalid("required username"), Valid)
```

I want to find the first one which has the type of `Invalid`:

```
results.find( ??? ) match {
    case Some(error) => println("Invalid: " + error)
    case _ => println("No error")
}
```

You can see there is a `???` in the `find`, but I don't know what shall I input there.

Answer (score 7):

```
results.find {
  case Invalid(_) => true
  case _ => false
} match {
  case Some(Invalid(error)) => println("Invalid: " + error)
  case _ => println("No error")
}
```

or maybe:

```
results.collectFirst {
  case Invalid(error) => error
} match {
  case Some(error) => println("Invalid: " + error)
  case _ => println("No error")
}
```

Not needed as is, but I would convert Valid into a case object, in case you want to pattern-match it.

Note: both versions return the first error found. If you want to accumulate errors, then you need to filter and map (or fold).

Answer (score 1):

Using list `span`,

```
val (v,inv) = results.span { _ match { 
    case Invalid(_) => false  
    case _ => true 
  } 
}
```

which returns

```
(v, inv) = (List(Valid),
            List(Invalid(required username), Valid))
```

In the resulting pair,

- the first element is a list of all valid results occurring from the beginning of the list,
- the second element is a list that starts with the first item that did not hold the predicate.

Thus we can extract the first invalid item with

```
if (inv.isEmpty) 
  Valid 
else 
  inv.head

res: Invalid(required username)
```